# Para fazer uma busca complexa eu teria que usar OR para combinar todas as instruções?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Eu gostaria de uma ajuda para fazer a SQL conforme os dados desta figura.

O que eu sei é que se eu enviar `AND` para todas as características e uma delas retornar `false` ou `erro` toda a SQL estará comprometida.

Eu pensei em fazer isso com `OR`. É o correto? Mas se eu fizer isso, um das características pode ser ignorado, não?

Segue o código que tenho até o momento

```
# Essa variável pega os tipos enviados por $_GET e separá-os.
$tipos  = (@explode('/', implode('/', $_GET['tipo'])));

# Esse foreach pega cada variável e monta a instrução
# **CATEGORIA LIKE '%{$word}% OR**
foreach($tipos as $word){
    $sql[] = "CATEGORIA LIKE '%{$word}%'";
}

# Então SQL pega o resultado do foreach e colocar no WHERE
# e eu termino de ordenar os resultados.
$sql    = 'SELECT * FROM imovel WHERE ' .implode(' OR ', $sql);
$sql   .= ' ORDER BY IMO_CODIGO DESC LIMIT '.$inicio. ', '. $limite;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Para a mesma categoria ex: tipo, dormintorios etc, pode usar o `IN` e depois o `AND` `SELECT * FROM tabela where dormintorio IN(1,2,3) AND tipo in('Casa', 'Cobertura')`

Comment: @perdeu se meu **tipo** retornasse `vazio`, isso não ia dar erro na SQL? Esta é a minha dúvida !!!

Answer (score 4):

## Montando um filtro

**ATENÇÃO:** Sempre valide suas variáveis antes da manda-las para o banco de dados.

### Validando o filtro

Se os valores são padrões, use na busca um código em vez de uma palavra, assim você sempre terá resultados consistentes.

```
$where = 'WHERE 1=1 AND ';

$tipo = Array(
  1, // Apartamento
  2, // Casa
  3  // Terreno
);

if (isset($tipo) && !empty($tipo)){

    // se $tipo for um array e for maior que 0
    if (is_array($tipo) && count($tipo) > 0) {
       $where .= " tipo IN ('".implode("','",$tipo)."') AND ";
    } else {
       $where .= " tipo = '{$tipo}' AND ";
    }

}

$dormitorio = Array(2,3,4); // Quantidade de dormitorios

if (isset($dormitorio) && !empty($dormitorio)){

   if (is_array($dormitorio) && count($dormitorio) > 0){
     $where .= " dormitorio IN ('".implode("', '", $dormitorio)."') AND ";

   } else {
     $where .= " dormitorio = '{$dormitorio}' AND ";
   }
}
```

<sub>Recomendo o envio do filtro via `POST`, mas também pode ser feito via `GET`, sem problemas. Lembre-se sempre de se previnir contra SQL Injection, aqui tem [uma pergunta sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php/3869#3869).</sub>

<sub>Valide os dados recebidos para checar quais campos entrarão na consulta como feito no exemplo acima (`if (isset($tipo) && !empty($tipo)){`, `if (isset($dormitorio) && !empty($dormitorio)){`, `if (isset($dormitorio) && !empty($dormitorio)){`), é bom fazer isso com as variáveis recebidas do formulário (`$_POST`, `$_GET`).</sub>

---

### Buscando uma Palavra-Chave

E caso o usuário possa fazer uma busca com palavra chave.

```
$palavrachave = 'Sacada';

if (isset($palavrachave) && !empty($palavrachave)){
  // Adicione todos os campos que possa ser buscado como palavra chave
  $where .= "(nome LIKE '%{$palavrachave}%' OR descricao LIKE '%{$palavrachave}%' OR cidade LIKE '%{$palavrachave}%') AND "; 
}
```

<sub>Adicione todos os campos que contenha conteúdo de texto na consulta da palavra-chave, caso você use isto no seu filtro. Monte um bloco entre parênteses usando `OR`, para que todos os resultados que tenha o termo em qualquer um dos campos, seja trazido no resultado, e concatene com o restante do filtro com `AND`.</sub>

---

### Montando tabela

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM imoveis ".trim($where,' AND ');
```

<sub>Coloque um `AND` depois de cada campo da consulta e quando for adicionar os campos na consulta remova apenas o último usando um `trim`. E mesmo que não haja nenhum filtro, não haverá problemas pois iniciamos o `WHERE` buscando todos os resultados onde `1=1` seja verdadeiro, ou seja, todos. E o `AND` dessa expressão será removido (`$where = 'WHERE 1=1 AND ';`), resultando em `WHERE 1=1`.</sub>

---

### Resultado

Todos os dados informados:

```
SELECT * FROM imoveis WHERE 1=1 AND  tipo IN ('1','2','3') AND  dormitorio IN ('2', '3', '4') AND (nome LIKE '%Sacada%' OR descricao LIKE '%Sacada%' OR cidade LIKE '%Sacada%')
```

<sub>A busca trará todos os dados que o campo tipo tenha o valor 1, 2 ou 3, informado na variável `$tipo`, que tenha o valor 2, 3 ou 4 no campo `dormitorio`, informado na variável `$dormitorio`, e que possua a palavra-chave `Sacada` no nome, descrição ou cidade, informada na variável `$palavrachave`.</sub>

Sem o campo `tipo` informado:

```
SELECT * FROM imoveis WHERE 1=1 AND  dormitorio IN ('2', '3', '4') AND (nome LIKE '%Sacada%' OR descricao LIKE '%Sacada%' OR cidade LIKE '%Sacada%')
```

<sub>A consulta retornará todos os dados que tenha o valor 2, 3 ou 4 no campo `dormitorio`, informado na variável `$dormitorio`, e possua a palavra-chave no nome, descrição ou cidade.</sub>

Nenhum campo informado:

```
SELECT * FROM imoveis WHERE 1=1
```

<sub>A consulta retornará todos os dados da tabela.</sub>

Comment: E caso **tipo** retornar vazio, ele vai ser descartado na SQL?

Comment: Sim, daí trará todos os resultados independente do tipo, pois ele não será adicionado no `WHERE` da consulta. Você tem que validar a variável, para que ela seja incluída ou não no filtro da consulta.

Comment: Como ficaria **$tipo** considerando que eu estou recebendo ele por `$_GET`? Estou recebendo `tipo=Apartamento&tipo=Casa&tipo=Terreno`.

Comment: Então, como eu disse ali na resposta `use na busca um código em vez de uma palavra`, mas caso não tenha como você fazer isso agora (mas procure fazer depois). Tente enviar os dados assim `tipo=Apartamento+Casa+Terreno`, e depois faça um explode `$tipo = explode('+',$_GET['tipo'])`. E depois é só seguir o modelo proposto.

Comment: Se você usar assim `tipo=Apartamento&tipo=Casa&tipo=Terreno`, o último sempre será sobreposto ao(s) anterior(es), você também pode fazer assim `tipo[]=Apartamento&tipo[]=Casa&tipo[]=Terreno`, que ai você receberá os dados corretamente.

Comment: vê se consegue me ajudar aqui >>> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35079/reescrever-o-c%C3%B3digo-para-exibir-resultado-esperado ... seu código está funcionando perfeitamente mas tenho um problema.

Comment: Já [ajudei lá](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35079/reescrever-o-c%C3%B3digo-para-exibir-resultado-esperado/35091#35091), [se essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35013/para-fazer-uma-busca-complexa-eu-teria-que-usar-or-para-combinar-todas-as-instru/35022#35022) foi útil, dê um _plus_ e marque como aceita.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve usar `and` e `or` separados em blocos com parenteses, por exemplo:

```
(tipo = apartamento or tipo = casa) and 
(dormitórios = 2 or dormitórios = 3) and 
(vagas = 1 or vagas = 2) and 
(area > 60 and area < 120) and 
(valor > 100000 and valor < 150000)
```

Desculpe a qualidade da resposta, estou no celular, assim que possível edito e melhoro...

Comment: Agora eu vou te expor o que pode ser o assunto dessa pergunta: e se tipo retornar `vazio`, isso vai retornar um erro na SQL não?

Comment: @MarcosVinicius Você terá que não incluir na query os filtros não preenchidos pelo usuário.

Comment: @Caffé poderia me mostrar isso em forma de SQL numa resposta?

Comment: @MarcosVinicius No caso, não tem SQL. A idéia é: você tem que ter a habilidade de saber se um filtro foi ou não preenchido pelo usuário. Os filtros preenchidos entram no seu comando SQL conforme descrito pelo Jader, e os filtros não preenchidos você simplesmente ignora. Ou seja: você terá que montar seu SQL dinamicamente com base no que foi ou não preenchido pelo usuário; você não poderá deixar a query pronta apenas passando os parâmetros na hora de executar. Consegui explicar?

Comment: Entendi isso @Caffé o negócio vai ser a habilidade em montar a SQL conforme os campos enviados. Obrigado pelo que já fez até agora.

Comment: @MarcosVinicius Se `tipo` não for preenchido pelo usuário ("retornar vazio"), não inclua um filtro para tipo na sua query. A query do Jader ficaria assim: `(dormitórios = 2 or dormitórios = 3) and (vagas = 1 or vagas = 2) and (área > 60 and área < 120) and (valor > 100000 and valor < 150000)`. Considerando que sua regra de negócio seja: "se usuário não selecionar um tipo, traga imóveis de qualquer tipo", o tipo simplesmente some da query.

Comment: @MarcosVinicius É isso mesmo. Por nada. E boa sorte!

Comment: @Caffé você consegue me mostrar um jeito de printar a sql que está sendo enviada para que eu possa visualizar a SQL que está sendo enviada além dos WARNINGS, FATAL etc ...