# Reescrever o código para exibir resultado esperado?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Este código deve retornar todos os registros da tabela **imovel** caso o array seja vazio e retornar registros selecionados caso se tenha itens na array.

Eu consigo fazer com que o array seja montado e o banco consultado caso eu selecione pelo menos um item do formulário mas não consigo retornar todos os valores do banco se o array chegar vazio. Na verdade ele não chega vazio, chega assim: `[0] =>` e é essa parte que dá erro.

```
# Selecionando o tipo de imóvel
$tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
$tipo = (@explode('/', implode('/', $tipo)));

if (isset($tipo) && !empty($tipo)){

    // se $tipo for um array e for maior que 0
    if (is_array($tipo) && count($tipo) > 0) {
       $where .= " CATEGORIA IN ('".implode("','", $tipo)."') AND ";
    } else {
       $where .= " CATEGORIA = '{$tipo}' AND ";
    }
}
```

*SQL sem itens do array:*

> SELECT * FROM imovel WHERE 1=1 AND CATEGORIA IN ('')

*SQL com itens do array:*

> SELECT * FROM imovel WHERE 1=1 AND CATEGORIA IN ('CASA')

***Formulário***

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tipo[]" value="CONJUNTOSALA/LOJA" id="tp5">
<label for="tp5">Conjunto/Sala/Loja</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="tipo[]" value="FLAT/LOFT" id="tp6">
<label for="tp6">Flat/Loft</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="tipo[]" value="PREDIO COMERCIAL" id="tp7">
<label for="tp7">Prédio Comercial</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="tipo[]" value="TERRENOS" id="tp8">
<label for="tp8">Terreno/Área</label>
```

Comment: O problema neste código é que mesmo que eu não selecione nenhuma item e envie o formulário com array **teoricamente vazio** ele compromete a SQL adicionando `AND CATEGORIA IN ('')` porque na verdade o array não está vazio e sim possui **1 índice vazio**.

Comment: Marcos evite esse tipo de gambiarras de `WHERE 1=1` e crie suas [querys de forma dinamica](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32521/busca-retorna-dados-iguais/32529#32529). Também elimine esse explode com supressão de erro (`@`).

Comment: Qual a finalidade da linha do implode/explode ? O php já transforma seu input em array sem precisar fazer isso ai: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/n0kp-9hmf

Comment: Tem índices que chegam sozinhos mas tem índices que chegam `APARTAMENTO/APTO DUPLEX` e eu preciso enviar estes termos individualmente, desmembrá-los no **/** (barra).

Comment: Não seria o caso de você dividir seu formulário em dois campos? `APARTAMENTO` e `APTO DUPLEX`?

Comment: Por questões de layout não é mais possível implementar esta solução, segue imagem: http://puu.sh/c2vtG/0348a1ad0f.png ... sem espaço pra mais campos e eles querem que envie 2 propriedades por input.

Comment: Você diz que cria sempre a query com `IN ('')` mesmo sem informar nenhum campo?

Comment: Neste caso, como a query cria um índice vazio `[0] => ` no submit do formulário, a afirmação `count($tipo) > 0` é **TRUE** e se é **TRUE** ele adiciona `AND CATEGORIA IN ('')` na SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua variável tem um índice vazio porque você está dando um `explode`. E não existe a necessidade desse `explode`. Então você pode fazer assim:

```
# Selecionando o tipo de imóvel
if (isset($_POST['tipo']) && is_array($_POST['tipo']) && count($_POST['tipo']) > 0){
   $where .= " CATEGORIA IN ('".implode("','", $_POST['tipo'])."') AND ";
}
```

De acordo com seu formulário, sua variável `$_POST['tipo']` sempre vai ser um *array*.

**Obs.: Não é recomendado enviar dados para o banco sem tratamento. Ou seja, pesquise sobre segurança e tratamento de variáveis antes de concatena-las com sua *Query SQL*.**